# Android: How to create a map by java code rather than by xml in google map api v2?

Tags: android, google-maps-api-2

In my android project, I would like to create a Google Map using java code rather than useing xml, how should I do?

Answer (score 2):

You can add a `Map` using `MapFragment` to an `Activity` in code. To do this, create a new `MapFragment` instance, and then call `FragmentTransaction.add()` to add the `Fragment` to the current `Activity`.

> ```
>    mMapFragment = MapFragment.newInstance();
>    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
>    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.my_container, mMapFragment);
>    fragmentTransaction.commit();
> ```

For more details check out the [GoogleMaps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/map), you will have more idea of implementing the maps.

Comment: very thanks my friend,I used your code but reported an exception as java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment, and finally I use SupportMapFragment to solve,like this SupportMapFragment fragment = new SupportMapFragment();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.ct, fragment).commit();